# hdfs dfs -put carpeta/archivo.json. No encuentra el archivo

Tags: hadoop

Trabajando con hadoop, con el sistema de archivos hdfs, trato de subir un archivo a una carpeta determinada pero no me encuentra la carpeta, como se ve en la imagen pude cargar la carpeta

[image: Cargar Carpeta]

Al tratar de subir un archivo a esa carpeta no me reconoce el archivo

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. ¿Has creado correctamente el directorio en HDFS?

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir nombreDirectorio
```

Comprueba que está correctamente creado:

```
hdfs dfs -ls /
```

2. Luego de esto podrías hacer la subida de fichero/s o directorio/s que necesites:

a. Subir un directorio

```
hdfs dfs -put /home/directorioOrigen /Destino
```

b. Subir un fichero:

```
hdfs dfs -put /ruta/fichero /Destino
```

c. Subir multiple ficheros:

```
hdfs dfs -put fichero1 fichero2 /Destino
```

Te recomendaría hacer un `hdfs dfs -ls` para verificar que esté correcto en el HDFS.

Comment: Muchas gracias!, tenia que darle la ruta completa

Answer (score 0):

También me sucedió.

1. Debes crear el archivo txt por separado por ejemplo:

```
$ nano maria.txt
```

2. Te pedirá el contenido del texto.
3. Ingresas el contenido y luego pones `ctrl + x`.
4. Le das en yes presionando y luego enter.
5. Para que te muestre el dato del contenido ingresas el comando:

```
$ cat maria.txt
```

6. por ultimo ingresas el comando:

```
 $ hdfs dfs -put maria.txt /TURUTA
```

`TURUTA` es la ruta de tu directorio en la cual estará el archivo

Espero te sirva. Saludos.